# What’s the difference between Intel XXVDA2 and XXVAM2?

Tags: interface, hardware

I have been looking at 25GBit NICs for SFP28 transceivers and came across the Intel XXV710 cards.

Since I couldn’t figure out the naming scheme of these NICs, I have no idea what the difference is between the XXV710DA2 and the XXV710AM2.

Is the DA2 just a newer version of the AM2 or are they completely different products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XXV710-DA2 is a PCIe add-in *card* made by Intel intended for direct-attach cable (*-DA*) with dual ports (*2*). You can use supported SR and LR optics as well.

The XXV710-AM2 is a dual-port network controller *chip* that can be placed on an third-party add-in card (similar to the -DA2) or incorporated on a server board or network appliance.

Comment: That makes sense to me when I read Intels Ark. But what confuses me is that fs.com seems to sell a card with AM2 in the SKU: https://www.fs.com/products/75603.html

Comment: That's apparently a card sporting the -AM2 chip, but not made by Intel (what would be a -DA2 card).